# c++ derived function not invoked

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, dll, polymorphism

**Sorry about all confusions, I wrongly typed the `::` for `:` in class inheritance, as well as missing the keyword `public`. It's always been `:`. Thanks again for all the helps.**

First the title might be too general, but I do not know a better way to describe the issue here.

What I have,

```
class __declspec(dllimport) Foo1:public Foo
{
  virtual BOOLEAN bar(Arg *arg);
}

class __declspec(dllimport) Foo2:public Foo1
{   
    virtual BOOLEAN bar(Arg *arg);  //newly added
}
```

both functions are implemented, and I have a function under Foo2 that

```
BOOLEAN Foo2::dosomething(Arg* arg)  //Question 1, should the position of * matter here?
{
  bar(arg);
}
```

But this still calls `Foo1::bar` instead of `Foo2::bar`. I double checked the signature and there is no problem. So I did some experiments,

1. Using [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) to compare the mangled function names exported in `Foo1` and `Foo2`'s dlls, results are

   `?bar@Foo1@@MAEEPAVARG@@@Z`
   `?bar@Foo2@@UAEEPAVARG@@@Z`
   Question2, should the difference of the letter in there or not?
2. Removing `bar` from `Foo1`, and then run, an error came up and said,

   `The procedure engry point ?bar@Foo1@@MAEEPAVARG@@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library libFoo1.dll`.

What I don't understand here is the call is under `Foo2` but it is still trying to find `Foo1`'s function. Also, there are multiple level of inheritance before `Foo1` and after `Foo2` so I'm not sure whether I'm missing something important in terms of function derivation usage or dll export, no expert on neither.

Hope I can get some suggestions on directions I should work on or possible causes.

Not sure whether I described the problem clear, feel free to modify it if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your actual class definitions, not just some member functions.

Comment: The posted code is certainly not C++, though: neither is `Class` a keyword (although `class` is), nor is the syntax `class T::S` part of C++ (ignoring the `__declspec(dllimport)` which is some non-C++ gibberish, either).

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by copying and pasting the code into a throw-away test program, compile it check problem is still present, throw out more stuff, test again, until problem is still present and you can't throw out any more.  Than if you still can't see it post test program to appropriate forum so other people can reproduce.

Comment: Sorry, typo on `Class`, should be `class`. Not sure about the syntax `class T::S`, that's what it is in the code.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, `class T::S` is perfectly valid, it is used to define the class `S` previously declared as a member of `T`. This is how you do pimpl.

Comment: @avakar: oh, right. But then the problem is obvious! The class is not a derived from whatever base class it is supposed to be derived from.

Comment: @Derek: please reduce the problem to example code that can actually be compiled and repo the problem. I think there are too many questions about the posted code to do anything more than guess about what the problem is.  For example, the difference in the mangled names indicates that `Foo1::bar()` is `protected`, while `Foo2::bar()` is `public`.  That's possibly an important detail (but maybe not), but it should be in the question's example code.

Comment: And just for the record, the answer to "Question 1" in the comment is: no, the location of any whitespace around the `*` in that declaration makes no difference to the compiler.

Comment: Another note: if you're still toward the novice side of C++ experience, I'd suggest not placing your classes into DLLs (or even  static libraries) until you get some more experience - at least get the classes working first, then move them into DLL/lib if you need to.

Comment: I've voted to close this as there is not enough information given to answer the question, and it's hard to tell what's being asked anyway.

Comment: __declspec(dllimport) is not gibberish at all, though it is non-standard.  Its used to export and import things when building code into DLLs.  Although usually one uses a macro which flips between export and import depending on whether you're building the DLL itself or the code using the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

BOOLEAN Foo2::dosomething(Arg* arg)  //Question 1, should the position of * matter here?

No the position of * does not matter.

Is the DoSomething function is a constructor or destructor?

Comment: Neither, just a member function.

Comment: That is strange, are you able to provide a compilable code sample that produces this effect?